# CSS Animations: Move elements in flow, if expandable is animated to open state

Tags: css, dom, css-transitions, auto

I am currently building a css transition for an expandable component.
Now I add a scale(Y) transform on the element when opening (scale 0 > 1) or reverse the animation on close:

```
    /*
 * Animation: Slide In from Top
 */

.u-slide-from-top-enter-active,
.u-slide-from-top-leave-active {
  transition-duration: $s-animation-duration-default;
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
  transform-origin: top;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.u-slide-from-top-enter,
.u-slide-from-top-leave-to {
  transform: scaleY(0);
  opacity: 0;
}

.u-slide-from-top-enter-to,
.u-slide-from-top-leave {
  transform: scaleY(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

This works all great, but Now the element below in the flow in the DOM jumps from one position to the other.

I first thought I could animate the height, but this does not work, then I thought I could animate the max-height, but this would not work with a value of `max-height: auto`.

So my question:
If I open the the expandable, can I somehow add some transition classes to the following elements in the DOM to transition their position (although I don't set a position property explicitely.

I find some help here:
https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/

But I don't want to use Javascript. If you see the javascript example you see the wanted behaviour, but I want it to make with css.

Thanks for inputs on that.

Cheers

Comment: Why aren't you able to animate the height? Can you share the full code including HTML?

Comment: Because of this: https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/#article-header-id-0